# Wordpress Xml Import Error

Tags: wordpress

Firstly I installed Wordpress, then I generate an XML file for a blog (akashujjwal.wordpress.com) tranfer by using the export tool. And when I try to import this XML file to an installed Wordpress then I face this error:

```
Import WordPress
Sorry, there has been an error.
File is empty. Please upload something more substantial. This error could also be caused by uploads being disabled in your php.ini or by post_max_size being defined as smaller than upload_max_filesize in php.ini.
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

The error basically tells you what to do.
Make sure the file ***isnt*** empty, make sure uploads ***arent*** disabled in your php,ini file.
Or as it states, the problem could be `post_max_size` being defined as smaller than `upload_max_filesize` in ***php.ini***.

Comment: so where could i check this . I'am trying to install a wordpress on a free host, and where i'll get the file php.ini

Comment: When youve installed wordpress, into your site dictionary and find the php.ini file.